# pyspark operations on datasets

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I recently started learning pySpark for network graph manipulation. I'm still trying to grasp how spark works using dataframes.

From what I understand:

1. Data in dataframes are distributed (the same way they are distributed with hadoop) on a cluster of machines.
2. Operations on dataframes are distributed the same way (or ,in my case, locally using a given number of threads) .

My main question is: Are only operations on dataframes distributed or all operations (lets say on python's dictionaries) distributed once they are executed in pyspark's shell?

Any further clarifications or articles are appreciated.

Comment: Usually it's only operations on dataframes. You can write UDFs and UDAFs to perform custom logic in distributed way, if you can't already perform this using the built-in aggregation functions.

Comment: @Hitobat Hello! So, if I understand this correctly, let's say I have a dictionary of 10 million key/value pairs. If I implement a UDF that takes the dictionary as an argument the operations will be done in distributed fashion, although the dictionary isn't a dataframe?

Comment: You can only run a udf on a dataframe, so you would first need to convert your input data. One way is you can save it as csv/json/avro and read it in using spark. Or directly convert in your program using `spark.createDataFrame()` or the older `spark.parallelize().toDF()`.

Answer (score 3):

Pyspark is an python API for spark, so there is a bridge between spark and python.  It is called [Py4j](https://www.py4j.org/contents.html), a lib that ensures data serialization and encoding from python language to JVM why ?

Spark is written in scala , a POO and FP language similar to java but it is different, as Java , scala is working on top of JVM (Java virtual machine). This process via Py4j makes data processing via spark slow compared to using scala or Java. When speaking about spark operations we speak about two types of operations : Actions and transformations: A transformation is a lazy evaluated operation, what does it mean by lazy evaluation ? It is a property in spark , basically a scala caracteristic when the expression/value is not evaluated until it is called and it stills in the memory, for this spark is in-momery computation engine. An action is an  operation that is directly evalued after the call like show, write, repartition....

I need to clarify a point too, there are two types of spark submit mode : client mode and cluster mode. Using a spark-shell is a client mode. I invite you to read more about these two modes and the difference between them. Any operation in spark ,after the submit, is distributed over all excutors in a yarn cluster or centos ... as you mentionned. Any transformation is not directly evaluated , after an action call spark creates something called [DAG](https://medium.com/@goyalsaurabh66/spark-basics-rdds-stages-tasks-and-dag-8da0f52f0454), here is an example of a spark DAG: [image: dag example] (Directed Acyclic Graph),this is used for the visual representation of RDDs and the operations being performed on them. The RDDs are represented by vertices, while the operations are represented by edges. Every edge is directed from an 'earlier state' to a 'later state. For each excutor, a task is asigned and after finishing that task, it informs the manager ( yarn /centos/...) about its state and so on.
You can read more about Dataframe , Dataset and RDD, but I can say that: RDD: Resilent distributed datasets, a collection of unstructered data in read-only mode (Immutable== we can not change it), dataframe are a collection of structured immutable data with a schema and dataset is like dataframe however it is typed.
[image]